# How come you can play Counter Strike almost immediately after you start downloading in Steam?

Tags: steam, counter-strike

I am curious as to how it is possible to start playing CS 1.6 after downloading so little from your Steam account.

The game is approximately 300 MB, and after something like 5% you can start playing. (The download even pauses while you're playing.)

How is that possible? Is that part of the game all there is to be able to play, what is all the rest?

Comment: Do you by chance have Half-Life or Team Fortress Classic installed already?

Comment: Er, I'm pretty sure this isn't true.  Are you sure you're not just downloading an *update* (in which case, you won't be able to connect to most servers running the latest version)?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft No, I'm not a gamer, the only game I have is Portal, maybe that is it, but it's the only game I have. This verified on THE FIRST TIME I downloaded, I'm sure of that.

Comment: @StrixVaria No, only Portal, the first one.

Comment: it might just be a compact engine downloaded first and all the rest are maps and textures

Comment: I don't know this for certain, so not an answer, but I believe that the game will launch even if you haven't downloaded all the data files - some of the largest parts of the game are maps, but the game can at least start without them.  I *think* it prioritizes the engine files over the maps.

Comment: ratchet freak is correct. The core source engine files are relatively small. Steam downloads them, then downloads player textures etc, then finally maps. If you choose a map then it will download it on the fly if it hasnt already done so.

Comment: @Cor_Blimey: If you're certain, make that an answer (with links to back up your claim)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft, I am not certain :P hehe... I also don't have the time to construct a worthy answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Steam allows for games to specify the minimum content required for launching a game.

This feature is more often used for single-player games where you wouldn't realistically need more than the first few levels right away.

From your description, it sounds like CS does the same, being that the maps and map-specific models are the largest pieces of content and you can't play all maps at the same time.